# How to use session authentication for nuxt frontend with adonis backend

Tags: nuxt.js, adonis.js

I used to use adonuxt which worked nice but it's depreciated. So I am now trying to use nuxt.js separate with adonis backend. I am trying to make login system. These two projects run on two separate port in localhost. `http://localhost:3000/` nuxt project and `http://localhost:3333/` adonis project.

How can I get logged in user information in nuxtServerInit?

I am trying like this

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { $axios }) {
 console.log('I am running as nuxt server init')

 try {
   // get the initial data
   let { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3333/myuser')
   commit('loginUser', data)
 } catch (e) {
     console.log('nuxt server error ', e.response)
  }
},
```

and in my adonis.js I am trying

```js
async getUser({request, response, params, auth}){
  try {
    const user = await auth.getUser()
    return user
  } catch (error) {
      return 'not logged in'
  }
}
```

The result is always `not logged in`....

Any idea how to implement.....

**UPDATE**

I am using a very simple login system

```js
async user({request, response, params, auth}){
   try {
      const user = await auth.loginViaId(34)
      return user
   } catch (error) {
      return error
   }
}
```

**I got a very interesting result now. So if I login using my adonis project then the logged in user information becomes available in nuxt project but I cannot get the logged in user if I login using nuxt axios**

**UPDATE 2**

So, session login works, but adonis cannot find user or loggedin user when axios is used.

**UPDATE 3**

we can get logged in user only using nuxtServerInit.. We can get the logged in user using axios.. :(

Comment: Can you share your login controller code?

Comment: Please check the question, I updated.

Comment: Can you add `credentials: true` to axios config (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#credentials)

Comment: I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/myuser' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.` error

Comment: I have cors enabled already but still this

Comment: okay try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Configure adonis

*config/session.js*

```js
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
    sameSite: 'strict',
    domain: Env.get('COOKIE_DOMAIN', null),
  },
```

*config/cors.js*

```js
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Credentials
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Define Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header. It should always be a
  | boolean.
  |
  */
  credentials: true, // Enable credentials cookies
```

> The Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header tells browsers whether to expose the response to frontend JavaScript code when the request's credentials mode (Request.credentials) is include.

More informations about Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header : [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

### Configure Nuxt

#### Enable axios credentials (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#credentials) :

*nuxt.config.js*

```js
  axios: {
    credentials: true,
  },
```

Comment: glad to hear it 

Comment: It was not sending coockie information before. Any idea how can I impliment csrf token in this approach? Adonuxt was a life saver :( but it's depreciated ....

Comment: Just add `@adonisjs/shield` (adonis), enable csrf and get csrf token from cookie `XSRF-TOKEN` (nuxt)